# Implementing two APIs with overlapping namespaces

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, aspose

Hello Stackoverflow community,

I try to implement 2 Projects together in a bigger project.
Due overlapping namespaces it is at the moment not possible for me to compile and run my code.
The two APIs I am using are Aspose.Cells and Aspose.PDF both have a rather big list of files I have to include into my Project. 
Now we come to my Problem when I try to compile my code I'll get mostly 2 sorts of errors.
The first one is for example

> System is ambiguous

that's caused by the fact that both libraries have a

> System folder

that contains several header files I need to run my code these files are NOT the same.
The second error would be  something like

> string is not a part of System

that error is also caused by the fact that each API got a System folder and my VisualStudio don't seem to properly know from which folder it has to load.
So for example if **Aspose.PDF** trys to call `Aspose:PDF:System:string` it actually tries to load `Aspose:Cells:System:string` since this is the API I imlpemented first but Aspose:Cells:System does not contain "string".
I would just `#include` all the files I need with a realtive path but the files I need also `#include` headerfiles which produce the same error so I'd have to change 100 or more headerfiles which to me seems like unneccessary afford and also just feels like the wrong approach.

What I tried to this point:
I implemented one of the APIs into my existing project and it runs flawlessly.
Whenever I implement the second one I get the errors descirbed above again.

Both APIs contains example projects which also runs withou a problem.
I first just tried to extend one of this example projects to run with the other one.
So I took **Aspose.Cells** and added all the neccessary Libraries,Dependencies and Directories from **Aspose.PDF** to my additional dependencies,Additional libraries and my additional include directories into the projects properties.
Which of course resulted in the same Errors.

Also I tried to add the **Aspose.PDF** example project into the **Aspose.Cells** solution but since I had to extend my additional include directories with the ones of **Apose.PDF** I ran into the same error again which makes totally sense.

So I guess now you should have a decent overview about my problem.
What would be a possible solution?
Would it maybe possible to order a header and all headers this header will include just to use a specific namespace or something like that?

Here are some of the Errors I get.

> Schweregrad   Code    Beschreibung    Projekt Datei   Zeile   Unterdrückungszustand
>   Fehler (aktiv)    E0266   ""Font"" ist
>   mehrdeutig.   Demo    E:\Aspose.Total_for_C++\Aspose.PDF\include\Aspose.Pdf.Cpp\Text\TextFragment.h   583 
>   Fehler (aktiv)    E0266   ""Font"" ist
>   mehrdeutig.   Demo    E:\Aspose.Total_for_C++\Aspose.PDF\include\Aspose.Pdf.Cpp\Text\TextFragmentAbsorber.h   492 
>   Fehler (aktiv)    E0266   ""Font"" ist
>   mehrdeutig.   Demo    E:\Aspose.Total_for_C++\Aspose.PDF\include\Aspose.Pdf.Cpp\Text\TextFragmentAbsorber.h   503 
>   Fehler (aktiv)    E0266   ""hash"" ist mehrdeutig.    Demo    C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include\unordered_map 91
>   Fehler (aktiv)    E0266   ""hash"" ist mehrdeutig.    Demo    C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include\unordered_map 638 
>   Fehler (aktiv)    E0266   ""literals"" ist mehrdeutig.    Demo    C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include\chrono    906 
>   Fehler (aktiv)    E0757   ""ptr"" ist kein
>   Typname.  Demo    E:\Aspose.Total_for_C++\Aspose.PDF\include\asposecpplib\drawing\drawing2d\matrix.h  152 
>   Fehler (aktiv)    E0757   ""ptr"" ist kein
>   Typname.  Demo    E:\Aspose.Total_for_C++\Aspose.PDF\include\asposecpplib\system\globalization\culture_info.h 55
>   Fehler (aktiv)    E0757   ""ptr"" ist kein
>   Typname.  Demo    E:\Aspose.Total_for_C++\Aspose.PDF\include\asposecpplib\system\text\icu_encoding.h  44
>   Fehler (aktiv)    E0519   "class "Aspose::Cells::System::Array"" darf keine
>   Vorlagenargumentliste
>   aufweisen.    Demo    E:\Aspose.Total_for_C++\Aspose.PDF\include\asposecpplib\system\io\text_writer.h 84
>   Fehler (aktiv)    E0519   "class "Aspose::Cells::System::Array"" darf keine
>   Vorlagenargumentliste
>   aufweisen.    Demo    E:\Aspose.Total_for_C++\Aspose.PDF\include\asposecpplib\system\io\text_writer.h 89
>   Fehler (aktiv)    E0519   "class "Aspose::Cells::System::Array"" darf keine
>   Vorlagenargumentliste
>   aufweisen.    Demo    E:\Aspose.Total_for_C++\Aspose.PDF\include\asposecpplib\system\io\text_writer.h 128 
>   Fehler (aktiv)    E0519   "class "Aspose::Cells::System::Array"" darf keine
>   Vorlagenargumentliste
>   aufweisen.    Demo    E:\Aspose.Total_for_C++\Aspose.PDF\include\asposecpplib\system\io\text_writer.h 133 
>   Fehler (aktiv)    E0519   "class
>   "Aspose::Cells::System::Collections::ICollection"" darf keine
>   Vorlagenargumentliste
>   aufweisen.    Demo    E:\Aspose.Total_for_C++\Aspose.PDF\include\asposecpplib\system\collections\base_dictionary.h    41
>   Fehler (aktiv)    E0519   "class
>   "Aspose::Cells::System::Collections::IEnumerator"" darf keine
>   Vorlagenargumentliste
>   aufweisen.    Demo    E:\Aspose.Total_for_C++\Aspose.PDF\include\asposecpplib\system\collections\keyvalue_collection.h    40
>   Fehler (aktiv)    E0135   "class "Aspose::Cells::System::Object"" hat
>   keinen Member
>   ""shared_members_type"".  Demo    E:\Aspose.Total_for_C++\Aspose.PDF\include\asposecpplib\system\collections\base_dictionary.h    306 
>   Fehler (aktiv)    E0135   "class "Aspose::Cells::System::Object"" hat
>   keinen Member
>   ""shared_members_type"".  Demo    E:\Aspose.Total_for_C++\Aspose.PDF\include\asposecpplib\system\io\memory_stream.h   156 
>   Fehler (aktiv)    E0135   "class "std::enable_if<, void>""
>   hat keinen Member ""type"".   Demo    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include\xtr1common    59
>   Fehler (aktiv)    E0135   "class "std::enable_if<, void>""
>   hat keinen Member
>   ""value"".    Demo    E:\Aspose.Total_for_C++\Aspose.PDF\include\asposecpplib\system\collections\iequality_comparer.h 85
>   Fehler (aktiv)    E0135   "class "std::enable_if<, void>""
>   hat keinen Member
>   ""value"".    Demo    E:\Aspose.Total_for_C++\Aspose.PDF\include\asposecpplib\system\collections\iequality_comparer.h 107 
>   Fehler (aktiv)    E0135   "class "System::ObjectExt"" hat keinen Member
>   ""Equals"".   Demo    E:\Aspose.Total_for_C++\Aspose.PDF\include\asposecpplib\system\object_ext.h 619 
>   Fehler (aktiv)    E0135   "class "_Ratio_multiply_sfinae, nano, false, void>"" hat keinen Member
>   ""type"". Demo    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include\ratio 223 
>   Fehler (aktiv)    E0757   "Funktion "Assembly"" ist kein
>   Typname.  Demo
>   E:\Aspose.Total_for_C++\Aspose.PDF\include\asposecpplib\system\reflection\assembly.h  84
>   Schweregrad   Code    Beschreibung    Projekt Datei   Zeile   Unterdrückungszustand
>   Fehler (aktiv)    E0135   "namespace "Aspose::Pdf"" hat keinen Member
>   ""PdfFormat"".    Demo    E:\Aspose.Total_for_C++\Aspose.PDF\include\Aspose.Pdf.Cpp\Document.h    1886
>   Fehler (aktiv)    E0135   "namespace "Aspose::Pdf"" hat keinen Member
>   ""SaveFormat"".   Demo    E:\Aspose.Total_for_C++\Aspose.PDF\include\Aspose.Pdf.Cpp\SaveOptions.h 232 
>   Fehler (aktiv)    E0135   "namespace "Aspose::Pdf"" hat keinen Member
>   ""SaveOptions"".  Demo    E:\Aspose.Total_for_C++\Aspose.PDF\include\Aspose.Pdf.Cpp\UnifiedSaveOptions.h  53
>   Fehler (aktiv)    E0135   "namespace "Aspose::Pdf"" hat keinen Member
>   ""TabOrder"". Demo    E:\Aspose.Total_for_C++\Aspose.PDF\include\Aspose.Pdf.Cpp\Page_.h   439

Comment: What `using` statements do you have in your code?

Comment: the example for **Apose:Cells** uses using namespace std and the one for **Aspose:PDF** uses System and System::Drawing but even wíthout any of these I can't compile

Comment: Overlapping namespaces should not be a problem without `using` statements.  Post your error messages when these statements are omitted (please add them to your question).

Comment: @PaulSanders Oke I added them to my question since there are over 6000 I guess you don't want them all

Comment: OK, thanks.  Very mysterious.  Did you omit those `using` statements, and did you check the header files you are including to see if those have any `using` statements also (they shouldn't, it's bad form)?

Comment: What are your include paths set to?

Comment: @alovaros, Would you please share narrowed down sample application reproducing this problem, via Google Drive, Dropbox etc., so that we may investigate and assist you accordingly. **PS:** I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Thanks to all of you I just did something really really stupid because I got unconcentrated....works now as intended thank you

Comment: Glad that your problem has been resolved. Feel free to contact us if you need any further assistance.